# zend uploaded location change

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am working with Zend framework version 1.9.5. I have uploaded a file to a temporary location using AJAX. When submitting the data, I need to move the file to its original location from the temporary location. How do I accomplish this. Is this possible without core PHP functions?

Comment: Just a little grammar.